# Why must a HSTS header not be sent on HTTP

Tags: https, hsts

Why must a HSTS header not be sent on HTTP?

What would it hurt; clients could take it as a hint to redirect to https.

Comment: Actually clients just will ignore it. Possible attack described here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797#section-14.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP requests can be manipulated by third parties (mitigating this is one of the main purposes of HTTPS). What happens if a third party modifies a HTTP response to add a HSTS header? Imagine that this happens to a site which does *not* support HTTPS. The client now attempts to access the site over HTTPS, which is not supported. Voilà: the third party has completely blocked access to the site (and for quite some time, if it was a long-term HSTS header).